# Why does core use print rather than echo?

Tags: theming

I've read somewhere, and I don't remember where, that `echo` is a more efficient way of outputting data then `print`.

Why does Drupal core use `print` so much? Is there any special reason behind that?

Comment: On a sidenote: print will always return 1 as a value, echo won't return anything. I guess that might be useful in some cases.

Comment: What kind of case that might be?

Comment: I've wondered that too! Good question!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`echo` is only faster in academic environments. The difference is very marginal. A quick benchmark I just did: The time fetching one row from a table with more than 2000 nodes is 1 unit.

In order to get an improvement of 1 unit, I would need to replace about 3.700.000 (over 3 milion) `print` statements with `echo`. In other words, if you want performance improvements, this is hardly the place to start.

Seen that `print` can be used in a much wider range of cases then `echo`, the first has some advantages. It leaves you three options:

- Always use `print`
- Use `echo` where possible and fallback on `print`
- Use `echo` always and refactor your code if `echo` cannot be used, to use it

Drupal has defaulted on the first.

To answer your actual question as to why this was chosen: It was not. It simply grew this way.

Comment: Could you provide an example of when echo cannot be used? It's just I can't imagine any at the moment.

Comment: The most obvious is `if (! print some_method() ) {print some_other_method()}`. Since print returns a TRUE if it actually printed something. Echo returns nothing, which is why it is faster too. Another example you will see is `return print $somevalue` at the end of a method to return the status.